# How do I specify iops parameter with io1 storage parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

I'm trying to create EC2 instance with Docker-Machine and I need to explicitly specify
`io1` storage so I searched and found I can call:

```
dm create -d amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key abc --amazonec2-secret-key def --amazonec2-instance-type "t2.small" --amazonec2-volume-type "io1" --amazonec2-region eu-west-2 app-prod
```

That gives me error:

`InvalidParameterCombination: The parameter iops must be specified for io1 volumes`

How can I specify the extra parameter `iops` ? There's no mention in `docker-machine create --help` output.

Comment: Sadly, you can't.  [This bug](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3189) has more details, but the short version is, it doesn't support the IOPS option, the only work around is to manually create an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/drivers/amazonec2/amazonec2.go) (at the time of this writing), there is no way to configure the volume’s IOPS through the `docker-machine create` command. docker-machine just routes the volume type through to the AWS API without evaluating it first, which in turn will throw the above error when the volume type is io1 or io2 and the IOPS option is missing.

This has already been raised as an [issue in the docker-machine project](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3189) in 2016 but hasn’t been resolved yet.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for chiming in. Since this can't be specified from cli I created the volume instance using GUI. I noticed it was assigned a volume ID. Can the ID be used while creating EC2 instance from cli ? To make it clear that I want the EC2 instance to use that particular volume instead of creating gp2 volume ?

Comment: Again, looking at the source code, I can’t find an option to attach an existing EBS volume. docker-machine appears to be very limited in this regard.